# Scope de la variable en PHP

Tags: php7

Quisiera saber como hago para que la variable $numeracion aumente su valor, lo que quiero lograr es que se muestre un orden numérico.

Lo que hice fue crear la variable $numeracion para que pueda sumarse sumar hasta que termine el "for", pero cuando veo los resultados, me sale solo el numero uno.

**Me sale así:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Este es mi codigo**

```
<?php
      for ($i = 8; $i < 14; $i++) { 
      $numeracion = 0;
?>

       <div class="row identificador<?= ($i + 1); ?>" style="text-align: left;">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2" style="text-align: justify;">
             <div class="form-group" style="text-align: justify;"> 
                 <input type="hidden" name="id<?= ($i + 1); ?>" value="<?= $preguntas[$i]["CSUP_ID"]; ?>" size="2" readonly style="border: thin;"/>
                 <?= ($numeracion + 1);?>.- <?= $preguntas[$i]["SSUP_PREGUNTAS"]; ?><samp id="clip<?= ($i + 1); ?>" style="display: none;color: #3c8dbc"> <i class="fa fa-paperclip" aria-hidden="true"></i> <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" onclick="quitar_foto(<?= ($i + 1); ?>)" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></samp>
             </div>
          </div>

       <?php $numeracion++; ?>

<?php
      }
?>
```

Comment: Necesitas declarar la variable fuera del `for`

Comment: funciono!!!!!!!

Comment: pero no entiendo, ¿como asi?

Comment: Si lo haces dentro del `for`, estas igualando a 0 en cada iteracion.

Comment: es cierto, cómo no he podido darme cuenta jeje. Y eso que me quede una hora inspeccionado todo el código. Gracias amigo @alanfcm.

Comment: Eso nos a pasado a todos alguna vez.

Comment: Pon tu solución como respuesta para marcarte como la definitiva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta que estas creando la variable dentro del ciclo for, en cada iteracion del ciclo la variable se vuelve a crear con un valor de cero

```
 $numeracion = 0; // se crea fuera del ciclo for
 for ($i = 8; $i < 14; $i++) {
   numeracion++; // se aumenta en 1

 }
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, aunque alguien ya me dio la solución al inicio, pero solo lo puso como comentario.

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en que estas declarando la variable dentro del `for`, por eso se iguala a 0 en cada iteracion.  La forma correcta seria asi:

```
<?php
      $numeracion = 0;
      for ($i = 8; $i < 14; $i++) {           
?>

       <div class="row identificador<?= ($i + 1); ?>" style="text-align: left;">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2" style="text-align: justify;">
             <div class="form-group" style="text-align: justify;"> 
                 <input type="hidden" name="id<?= ($i + 1); ?>" value="<?= $preguntas[$i]["CSUP_ID"]; ?>" size="2" readonly style="border: thin;"/>
                 <?= ($numeracion + 1);?>.- <?= $preguntas[$i]["SSUP_PREGUNTAS"]; ?><samp id="clip<?= ($i + 1); ?>" style="display: none;color: #3c8dbc"> <i class="fa fa-paperclip" aria-hidden="true"></i> <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" onclick="quitar_foto(<?= ($i + 1); ?>)" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></samp>
             </div>
          </div>

       <?php $numeracion++; ?>

<?php
      }
?>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, aunque alguien ya me dio la solución al inicio, pero solo lo puso como comentario.